# How to highlight a text in tableview cell?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody,is it possible to highlight a text-label.text in a table-view cell not the entire row .I want to highlight only the text in the table-view,i don't want the entire row selection when we tap the cell.My requirement is when i tap the cell,it highlighted the contents of the cell which means the text of the cell.Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override setHighlighted and do something else.

```
- (void)setHighlighted: (BOOL)highlighted animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    // change your text label background color here
}
```

Comment: can u explain?i want to highlight the text when i tap the cell.

Comment: i didnt know how to override ,i am a newable in this iphone development,so please explain in detail.thanks